# Oracle : how to order hexadecimal field

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, alphanumeric

Silly question but I can't find a reasonable answer.

I need to order a field containing **hexadecimal** values like :

```
select str from
    (
    select '2212A' str from dual union all
    select '2212B'     from dual union all
    select '22129'     from dual union all
    select '22127'     from dual union all
    select '22125'     from dual union all
    select '22126'     from dual
   ) t
   order by str asc;
```

This request give :

```
STR         
------------
2212A
2212B
22125
22126
22127
22129
```

I would like

```
STR         
------------
22125
22126
22127
22129
2212A
2212B
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Define "smallest value".  Is that the value that sorts first alphabetically?  Or should we extracting the numeric data and doing a numeric sort?

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks for your comment. I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: When I take your statement and run it on SQL Fiddle, I get the result you are looking for.  Are you sure that you aren't?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/27761  Is your database character set EBDIC-based rather than ASCII-based?

Comment: @JustinCave I don't have the same result as your SQL fiddle. My NLS_CHARACTERSET is WE8MSWIN1252. Should I change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are these HEX numbers? Will the max letter be F? Then convert hex to decimal:

```
select str
from t
order by to_number(str,'XXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

EDIT: Stupid me. The title says it's hex numbers :P So this solution should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clarify further what you want to achieve, but in general, you can sort your table on that column and the first row is the one with smallest value:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY mycolumn
```

If you want one record only:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY mycolumn WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have updated my question with more details

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like a *try_convert()* in case the conversion fails.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(VARBINARY, column_name) ASC;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like a `NLSSORT()` this solved my issue.

```
select * from mytable order by NLSSORT(your_column , 'NLS_SORT=BINARY'))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).